# Java Hibernate Different Behavior between starting jar from console and explorer with double click

Tags: java, hibernate, console

In my JavaFx project I use Hibernate to connect to a local Postgresql database.
In Intellij the project runs and the connection works. Also when I start the formed jar from the console everything works and the data can be read.
However when I start the jar from the explorer with a double click it does not work. Also no error is given.

```
@FXML
protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        System.out.println("Test");
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Appdssdasdalication!");

        try{
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("test");
            alert.showAndWait();
            session.beginTransaction();



            Name name = new Name();
            name.setEmail("p.gue@gmail.com");
            name.setEmployeeId(1);

            session.save(name);

            session.getTransaction().commit();


            session.beginTransaction();

            String email = session.get(Name.class, 1).getEmail();
            welcomeText.setText(email);
            alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText(email);

            alert.showAndWait();
            //welcomeText.setText(((Name)session.createQuery("From Name").list().get(0)).getEmail());
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        }catch(Exception e){
            welcomeText.setText(e.toString());

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText(e.toString());

            alert.showAndWait();
        }

        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to sadssaddsadsaasd Appdssdasdalication!");

    }
```

the first test alert is not opened when started via double click.

Java JDK 16.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check the association for the `.jar` extension. It may be associated with another (older) JRE.

Comment: i have changed the assosiation to the java jdk 16 bin/java.exe. But then a black console opens and closes immediatly. Nothing happens then.

Comment: Open a console and run `path\to\java16\bin\java -jar yourapp.jar`.

Comment: It works in the console. My Problem is the double click in the explorer.

Comment: Then maybe the `-jar` part is missing in the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to my question.

The problem was the hibernate.cfg.xml. I have loaded this file within my program.
But when I double clicked my jar the working directory was another one. So he couldnt find the cfg.xml.

Thanks for your help!